# How to remove lines which start with something in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove all lines, which start with the letter "C" in the column"InvoiceNo".cI couldn't find an answer here that is why  I would appreciate any help. 
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import xlsxwriter
import re


dataset = pd.read_excel('OnlineRetail2.xlsx')
dataset.head()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code *as text*. A picture of code doesn't help anyone. (The result table is still helpful and fine to leave as a picture, however.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could provide some sample data in plain text, it would help me test this, but I believe this should do the trick.

```
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset.InvoiceNo.str[0] != 'C'].copy()
```

Basically select those rows where `dataset.InvoiceNo` does *not* start with the letter C, and then reassign your dataset to a copy of just those rows (throw everything else out).

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude any line starting with a comment when reading a file in pandas. For excel:

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('OnlineRetail2.xlsx', comment="C")
```

Search for 'comment' [in the 'read_excel' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset[dataset["InvoiceNo"].str[0] != "C"]
```